# getResources().getString() doesn't work after orientation has been changed

Tags: android

My android application is in dual language. So I have 2 res folder value and value-sw(for swahili). I am fetching string values from this file in design and also at run time. For example in layout:

```
android:hint="@string/Officer"
```

and in code:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.Officer);
```

To change the locale setting I have function which I call on onCreate() which looks like this:

```
public void ChangeLanguage(Context ctx,String Language){
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
        config.locale = new Locale(Language.toLowerCase());
        res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
}
```

All works fine. Problem comes only if I change the orientation.

For example on start up I set the language to Swahili. So everything is in Swahili. Now if I change the orientation from vertical to horizontal or vice-verse.  Textbox box hint which was set in layout remains in Swahili which I expect. But getResources().getString(R.string.Officer); fetches value from the default value file, which is English.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**

Doing so will cause your activity not to be destroyed and re-created when orientation is changed.

Comment: Hi @Waqas thanks for your reply. I already have that setting in my Menifest file.

Comment: paste a part of your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".EnrollmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: are you overriding onConfigurationChanged in your activity code?

Comment: No am not doing anything in onConfigurationChanged. But one thing I don't understand is how it still reads the correct value in layout and not in the code?

Comment: what do you mean? can you post your complete activity class in question? because with this all info, its still clear

Comment: Lemme try to explain my question again in case it wasn't clear. When application starts I display on alertDialog to select language. Then user choose swahili. Now he will get layout in Swahili language. There is a textbox and hit is set something like this @string/Offier. And I I have a button and onClick I retrieve the same string like this getResources().getString(R.string.Officer). both will display the details in Swahili. Now I change the orientation. Now what happens textbox still displays hins in swahili but on button click it will fetch string from english instead of swahili. Thats it.

Comment: when you click the button, from where does it fetch string? did you mean resources? technically, whenever you load new activity, you must need to set language by calling ChangeLanguage method. Its not like you set it once and it remains the same through out the app's lifecycle

Comment: Thats what I do i have copied the code where I change Locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with having the `android:configChanges` attribute, is that that disables onCreate() from being called after an orientation change. You are basically telling the app: "I know there will be orientation changes, so don't recreate the screen, I will handle it"

I would suggest calling that function of yours in the `onConfigurationChanged()` method. Have in mind that any views will be null at that point, so if you need them you will need to get a new reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have same case as one in the question, using English and Swahili in an app. 
This is how I tackled it : I created a folder called `values-sw` then in the folder I created a resource file named `string.xml`. this is where all my Swahili translations are written. I call the following method in onCreate:

```
 public static void setLocale(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userLocale = sharedPreferences.getString("userlocale", null); // adapt to your need
    if (userLocale != null) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(userLocale);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Dont forget to refresh your activity for changes to take effect:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

(I know it's pretty late for this answer I hope it helps someone out there, cheers!)